# data type size - wondering about a good post

Tags: c

I just read an excellent post, [Portable Fixed-Width Integers in C](http://www.netrino.com/node/140), everything makes perfect sense till the almost the end, I am wondering what does the following paragraph means:

Of course, if you don't have a C99-compliant compiler yet you'll still have to write your own set of typedefs, using compiler-specific knowledge of the char, short, and long primitive widths. I recommend putting these typedefs in a header file of your own design and adding the anonymous union declaration shown in Listing 2 to a linked source module to check their sizes; that is, to gently "remind" whomever might someday have the task of porting your code.

```
static union
{
    char   int8_t_incorrect[sizeof(  int8_t) == 1];
    char  uint8_t_incorrect[sizeof( uint8_t) == 1];
    char  int16_t_incorrect[sizeof( int16_t) == 2];
    char uint16_t_incorrect[sizeof(uint16_t) == 2];
    char  int32_t_incorrect[sizeof( int32_t) == 4];
    char uint32_t_incorrect[sizeof(uint32_t) == 4];
};
```

Listing 2. This anonymous union allows a compiler to detect and report typedef errors

I experimented a small program:

```
typedef unsigned char  int8_t;
typedef unsigned short int16_t;

union u {
    char int8_incorrect[sizeof(int8_t)==1];
    char int16_incorrect[sizeof(int16_t)==2];
};


int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

There is no issue going through compiler. I changed int8_t into the following:

```
typedef unsigned int  int8_t;
```

There is no issue either.

Basically I missed the point why this example code can detect error.

Could you clarify what I missed?

Comment: Did you compile with full error reporting on?

Comment: Btw., assuming that e.g. `sizeof(int16_t) == 2` is not portable. On some embedded systems, `sizeof(int16_t) == 1`.

Comment: I think it needs to be tweaked so the sizes turn to a number less than zero. Perhaps something more like: `[1 - 2 * (sizeof(xxx)==yyy)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile with `gcc`  add `-std=c89 -pedantic` or `-std=c99 pedantic` to your `gcc` compile options to get the warning with this typedef and the union type:

```
typedef unsigned int  int8_t;
```

For this typedef:

```
typedef unsigned char int8_t;
```

it is normal you don't get any warning, as the trick is to check the size of type, not wether it is a signed or unsigned type.

Comment: That is it. After using -std=89 and -pedantic, I get the warning: warning: ISO C forbids zero-size array 'int8_incorrect'

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that arrays of length 0 are disallowed by the C standard. If you write `sizeof(int8_t) == 1` as the array length, and `sizeof(int8_t)` is *not* 1, the comparison will evaluate to 0, and you will have an illegal array size.

However, the following link shows that GCC *does* allow zero-length arrays:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html

...so if you are using GCC, that might be the reason you didn't get an error.